# How to create UI in C++ visual

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am new to C++ and visual studio, can anyone please help me in creating an UI for below requirements?

Requirement: There is a .txt file which consists of 10 test cases. In the UI, I(tester) should be able to select his/her choice of test cases to run.

Comment: Please, clarify what kind of user interface you want. GUI (graphical user interface) allowing usage of mouse to select radio buttons, or Console application (textual user interface) just to enter numbers (or letters) for selection?

Comment: And what is the structure of txt-file with test cases? Is a test case a number, or set of numbers in one line, or something else?

Comment: The testlist.txt file looks like this:01_DVBT_Short_A7_SensHigh.txt
02_DVBT_Short_A7_SensLow.txt
03_DVBT_Short_A1_CRHigh.txt
04_DVBT_Short_A1_CRLow.txt
07_DVBT_Short_A11_AWGN_4QAM.txt
08_DVBT_Short_A11_AWGN_16QAM.txt
09_DVBT_Short_A11_AWGN_64QAM.txt
11_DVBT_Short_A10_CoChannel.txt

Comment: each testcase file is doing some operations, my requirement is like TESTCASENAME [YES/NO] if we select Yes the testcasename.txt file will be executing (I don't which one to be applicable for this application GUI/Console application suggest me which one is best for my requiremnt)

Comment: So a testcase is defined with file name. And how this file name is used in a test? Explain, which operations txt file can do? File name is given to some function as parameter, or your program should open file (e.g. 03_DVBT_Short_A1_CRHigh.txt when 3rd test case is selected) and do something with contents of this file to perform a test?

Comment: @Jagan For UI with YES/NO question, console app is quite suitable, but I still do not understand how you are planning to execute test... perhaps, you do not need C language.... Do you consider using bash (command file)?

Comment: As it is of the time of writing, **this is a bad question.** It needs to be expanded upon.

Comment: @Jagan: I have updated program template for Y/N test case execution. Try and explain details.

Comment: Reading the testcase files (within the C++ program which contains the input parameters for the code files) into code and running the testcase once it is finished we go for the other testcae and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a `MFC` project. You can find drop-down menus in GUI toolbox.
Learn further in  `MFC`.

refer this - [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hSYZdvQ3s4&index=1&list=WL](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hSYZdvQ3s4&index=1&list=WL)

Answer (score -1):

Consider the possibility to use command line interface as the following template shows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // check that parameter is given in command line when program is run
    if(argc != 2) // if number of parameters is insufficient 
    {   // explaine and stop
        cout << "Please, run a program with parameter: name of file with testcases" << endl;
        cout << "For example:" << endl << " " << argv[0] << " tests.txt" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    // try to open file with test cases
    ifstream testfile;
    testfile.open(argv[1], ifstream::in);
    if( !testfile.is_open() )
    {
        cout << "ERROR: File " << argv[1] << " cannot be open!" << endl;
        return 2;
    }
    // read test cases from file
    string testCaseName;
    char answer;
    while( getline(testfile, testCaseName).good() )
    {
        if(testfile.eof())
        {
            break;
        }
        if(testCaseName.length() == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        cout << "Would you like to execute testcase " << testCaseName << " ? (Y/N): ";
        cin >> answer;
        if( answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y')
        {
            cout << "Test execution... " << endl;
            // run test case
            // . . .
            // report test results
            // . . .
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

To run your test with such program you should type in the command line:

```
 programname test_file.txt
```